# Hausdorff dimension and sigma finiteness

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, fractals

If a function $ f : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R} $ is $\mathscr{C}^{0,\alpha}$ for every $ 0 < \alpha < 1 $ then its graph has Hausdorff dimension $1$.

I would like to see an example of such a function with a NON $\sigma$ finite graph (with respect to $\mathscr{H}^{1}$).

Comment: Do you know such examples exist or are you implicitly asking whether or not they do?

Comment: I do not know if such example exists. However I would be surprised if it does not, because in several papers I have seen non trivial proofs for the $\sigma$ finiteness of the graphs of functions in special subclasses of the class $\bigcap_{0 < \alpha < 1}\mathscr{C}^{0,\alpha}$, everyone using some special feature of the subclass.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am sure there is an example with a non $\sigma$-finite 1-measure.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the [Takakgi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) satisfies this property. According to [The Takagi Function: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1691v2), the Takagi function $T$ satisfies
$$T(x+h)-T(x) = O(h\log(1/|h|) \: \text{ as } \: h\to0$$
and this is the best possible estimate.

Of course, lower bounds for Hausdorff measure are tricky but I think the result you need can be found in the paper [On the Hausdorff Dimension of Some Graphs](http://www.math.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no60.pdf) by Mauldin and Williams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this survey they claim that the graph is $\sigma$ finite, see p.16. Actually the fact that the takagi function has $\sigma$ finite graph was the initial motivation for my question.